B Popover in bootstrap get closed when clicked element inside it when trigger is set with and click blur
Good day developers ..im using a component with b-popover component form vuebootstrap.
Inside that b-popover i have collapsable component that is also from vue bootstrap(b-collapse).
The intention is having in the parent component(Popover) a button that triggers the collapse, then once  this collapse its shown it will emit an event boolean that will be listened by the parent component to dynamically assign a boolean value to a data property which eventually will allow or not the exposure of that button that triggers the collapse. Literally a button that open the collapse inside the popover, and once this is opened the button should disappear.
With this intention i have settled my code ..but then when clicking that button ..the collapse expands, the button disappears, but right away the popover self close cause the trigger method in it has the property blur(is needed)..how to avoid this situation?...i just want to expand my collapse child component..i would like to not expose the button in the popover that triggers that collapse, and also avoid the popover self closing while this happen, but just if i click outside it, or click any other button that indicates so
Here my parent component Popover:

<template>
  <b-popover
    triggers="click blur"   
    @shown="onShow"
  >
  <collpase-component
        @toggle="handleCollpsable($event)"
      ></collpase-component>
        <div v-if="!isTextAreaCollapsed">
            <btn
              v-b-toggle.collapse-comment-area
            />
      ...more tags html....
</template>
<script>
   export default{
     name:Popver,
     data() {
      return {
        isTextAreaCollapsed: false,
      };
     },
     methods:{
         handleCollpsable(value) {
              this.isTextAreaCollapsed = value;
         },
     }

   } 
</script>

then my child component Collapse:
<template>
  <b-collapse id="collapse-comment-area" class="mt-4" @shown="toggleOpen" @hidden="toggleClose">
    <div class="d-flex w-100">
      <b-form-textarea
        id="textarea"
        v-model="text"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        class="bg-gray-800 w-100"
      ></b-form-textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row w-100 justify-content-end my-3">
      <btn v-for="button in buttons" @click="button.buttonAction" :key="button.text" :class="button.buttonClass">
        <i :class="button.icon"></i> {{ button.text }}</btn
      >
    </div>
  </b-collapse>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CollpaseComponent',

    props: {
      ...some props....
    },

    data: () => {
      return {
        text: '',
      };
    },

    
    methods: {
      submit() {},
      toggleOpen() {
        this.$emit('toggle', true);
      },

      toggleClose() {
        this.$emit('toggle', false);
      },

      
    },

    computed: {
      ........
    },
  };
</script>


